# add a scrollView in a view iphone

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, scrollview

I have a form View with some UITextFields in it. I want to add form's view in a scrollview.

Following is how I designed the form and its textfields:

```
    - (UIView *)Form
{
    if (!_Form) {

        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, Height, Width, 310.0);
        UIView *container = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

        CGFloat y = 15.0;
        frame = CGRectMake(15.0, y, width, height);
        UITextField *field = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        [
        field.placeholder = @"text";


        CGFloat spacing = 8.0;
        y = frame.origin.y + height + spacing;
        frame = CGRectMake(15.0, y, kDeviceWidth - 2*15.0, height);
        field = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

        field.placeholder = @"text6";


        frame.size.height = 200.0;

        y = frame.origin.y + height + space;
        frame = CGRectMake(15.0, y, width - 2*15.0, height);
        field = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

        field.placeholder = @"text1*";



        y = frame.origin.y + height + 16.0;
        CGFloat w = (kDeviceWidth - 2 * 15.0) / 2;
        frame = CGRectMake(15.0, y, w - 2.0, height);
        field = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

        field.placeholder = @"text3*";


        frame = CGRectMake(15.0 + w + 2.0, y, w - 2.0, height);
        field = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

        field.placeholder = @"text4*";


        y = frame.origin.y + height + spacevalue;
        frame = CGRectMake(15.0, y, w, height);
        field = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

        field.placeholder = @"text5";



        y = frame.origin.y + height + 20.0;
        frame = CGRectMake((frame.size.width - 192.0) / 2, y, 192.0, 34.0);



        y = frame.origin.y + height + 8.0;
        frame = CGRectMake((frame.size.width - 192.0) / 2, y, 192.0, 34.0);
    }
    return _Form;
}
```

I have added this in "textFieldDidBeginEditing":(signView is the view which has form's view in it)

```
 UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.signView.frame.size.width, self.signView.frame.size.height)];
       scroll.pagingEnabled = YES;
       [scroll addSubview:self.Form];

       scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.signView.frame.size.width*self.Form.frame.size.width, self.Form.frame.size.height);
```

but when I tap on a textfiled ALL the textfields of the form view disappear.how can I embed my scrollview in a from view?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are doing `return _Form;`

What is `_Form`.

As i understand you have to return `container`.
so make it

`return container;`

And you are making `UITextField` but where are you adding as subView to your view, You are just creating it.

Comment: I am creating textfields in a form's view in " - (UIView *)Form"

Comment: you are doing return _Form; so what is this _Form

Comment: _form is a registration Form view

Comment: where are you allocating it>

Answer (score 0):

Yes but you have to put your UITextField in container which is your container by adding subview

```
    if (!_form) {
      //YOUR STUFF then -> add container subview your view  
      [container addSubview:yourTEXTField]
      return container;
    }
    else { 
      return _form;
    }
```

Comment: can you help me to add a scroller to the view I have implemented?